# errorprovider looks different on form loading

Tags: c#, winforms

I use an **ErrorProvider**

```
   errorProvider.SetIconAlignment(btnOk, ErrorIconAlignment.BottomLeft);
   errorProvider.SetError(btnOk, errorMessage);
```

If the error is set in the forms "Load" event, the icon looks distorted (white halo).

Any other time, it looks fine.
Can someone please help?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I've seen this complaint before, never been able repro it myself.  Afaik this is a Windows bug.  It is DrawIconEx() that needs to resize the icon and it seems to fumble the background color sometimes.  Impossible to nail down because users never post reliable repro code and never mention their Windows version.

Answer (score -1):

Just a DrawIconException , it has been handled in newer versions like Visual studio 2013 ultimate